# Getting the range in when given two date between

Tags: vb6

i have a simple program in VB6. i have two text box and one list box. i have put date ranges in text box and result comes in List box. example one text box 02/05/2012 and another text box 02/10/2012. the results comes in list box

02/05/2012
02/06/2012
02/07/2012
02/08/2012
02/09/2012
02/10/2012

any one guide me

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim dtStart As Date, dtEnd As Date

If Not IsDate(Text1) Then
    MsgBox "Text1 does not contain a valid date"
    ' Exit Sub/Function
End If

If Not IsDate(Text2) Then
    MsgBox "Text2 does not contain a valid date"
    ' Exit Sub/Function
End If

dtStart = CDate(Text1)
dtEnd = CDate(Text2)

' Clear the listbox
List1.Clear

Dim d As Date
For d = dtStart To dtEnd
    List1.AddItem d
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

See this page from MSDN which explains how the DateDiff function works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx. Now it's only matter of retrieving the data from the listbox.

Answer (score -1):

if your are using javascript then see this one

```
function (startDate, endDate, addFn, interval) {

 addFn = addFn || Date.prototype.addDays;
 interval = interval || 1;

 var retVal = [];
 var current = new Date(startDate);

 while (current <= endDate) {
  retVal.push(new Date(current));
  current = addFn.call(current, interval);
 }

 return retVal;

}
```